# Переключение фрагментов через getActivity()

Tags: android-fragment, android

Есть класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

final int DIALOG_EXIT = 1;

FragmentTransaction ft;

FirstFragment ff = new FirstFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ff = new FirstFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, ff)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("EXIT").setMessage("Уверен что хочешь выйти?^^").setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Нет", null).show();
    }

}}
```

А также три одинаковых фрагмента

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentTransaction ft;
SecondFragment sf;
ThirdFragment tf;
Button next1;
Button back1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, null);
    sf = new SecondFragment();
    tf = new ThirdFragment();
    Button next1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.next1);

    Button back1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.back1);

    next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.next1:
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame, sf).addToBackStack(null);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            ft.commit();

        }
    });

    back1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.back1:
                    //((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.back1));
                    //getActivity()
                    //(MainActivity()getActivity()).
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame, tf).addToBackStack(null);

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            ft.commit();

        }
    });
    return v;
}}
```

Фрагменты переключаются внутри себя, каким образом сделать переключение через ((MainActivity)getActivity())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

советую сделать через callback.
т.е. описываете интефейс у фрагмента

```
public interface DoSomesingListener
{
     public void doSomesing();
}
```

и делаете приватное поле у фрагмента(у всех фрагментов) или же у одного базового фрагмента и все фрагменты наследуете от этого. с наследованием предпочтительней, т.к. не будет повторения 
кода

```
private  DoSomesingListener doSomesingListener;
```

и setter к нему

```
public void setDoSomesingListener(final DoSomesingListener doSomesingListener)
{
   this.doSomesingListener = doSomesingListener;
}
```

Затем в нужном активити реализуете данный интерфейс и посылаете  фрагментам, где должны выполняться эти действия, через **setDoSomesingListener**

Надеюсь понятно описал свою мысль.

Но можно и как вы предлагали, но я бы так не стал делать.

**UPD:**  получилось довольно массивно, советую сопоставить написанное выше, с кодом ниже

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BaseFragment.OnFragmentChangeListener
    {

        private OneFragment oneFragment;
        private TwoFragment twoFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //предварительно переменный oneFragment и twoFragment
            //должны быть инициализированны
            //далее посылаем слушателя в каждый фрагмент
            oneFragment.setOnFragmentChangeListener(this);
            twoFragment.setOnFragmentChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFragmentChange()
        {
            //тут происходит переключение фрагментов,
            //логику уж не знаю, придется делать самому
        }

    }

    public class BaseFragment extends Fragment
    {
        //тут происходит всякая инициализация и другой код

        public interface OnFragmentChangeListener
        {
            //методо может иметь входные параметры(так, для справки)
            public void onFragmentChange();
        }

        protected OnFragmentChangeListener onFragmentChangeListener;

        public void setOnFragmentChangeListener(final OnFragmentChangeListener onFragmentChangeListener)
        {
            this.onFragmentChangeListener = onFragmentChangeListener;
        }

        //этот метод не обязателен, так как поле onFragmentChangeListener с модификатором protected,
        // а значит все наследники класса имеют к нему доступ
        // написал на всякий случай
        public OnFragmentChangeListener getOnFragmentChangeListener()
        {
            return this.onFragmentChangeListener
        }

    }

    public class OneFragment extends BaseFragment
    {
        //тут происходит всякая инициализация и другой код
        private void wantChangeFragment()
        {
            if (onFragmentChangeListener!=null) 
                onFragmentChangeListener.onFragmentChangeListener();

        }
    }

    public class TwoFragment extends BaseFragment
    {
        //тут происходит всякая инициализация и другой код
        private void wantChangeFragment()
        {
            if (onFragmentChangeListener!=null) 
                onFragmentChangeListener.onFragmentChangeListener();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Слушай, у тебя есть facebook или vk?)

Comment: Или напиши пожалуйста подробнее

Comment: до завтра предлагаю подумать :)   
сегодня уже не могу ничего делать.

Comment: Не помогло)